# Is there an acoustic fingerprint tagging for audiobooks in mp3 format?

Tags: linux, mp3, tags, audiobook

I am looking for a linux-based solution that will automatically tag my audiobooks, which are mp3 files.

I do not want my audiobooks listed as music, this makes the music libary very messy.

There is a lot of untagged/bad filename audiobooks, I hate to have to manually tag/rename them. How does everyone else handle this problem?

Thank you kindly

Answer (score 1):

Probably there isn't. I always keep my audiobooks seperated in different folder. Always buy/download audiobooks you actually listen to.